# how to parse json with volley in java

Tags: java, json, android-volley

Til now I have to create json in php using array-data-name like this :

```
print "{data : ".json_encode($the_data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."}"
```

in android studio in java I do like this :

```
String url = "httpmywebsite";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i  ) {
                                        JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        String id = respons.getString("id");
                                        String name = respons.getString("name");
                                        String email = respons.getString("email");

}
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
                    }
                }

                );
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
```

it works fine, but now I want to update my php file

from :

```
print "{data : ".json_encode($the_data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)."}"
```

to ;

```
print json_encode($the_data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

so I have tried to update my java code for volley like below but not work !

```
JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response.toString());
```

the new php code returns this json :

```
[{"0":"100","id":"100","1":"sandra","name":"sandra","2":"x@x.com","email":"x@x.com"}]
```

I have added this code to get the error type of volley ;

```
@Override
```

public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

```
if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
    Toast.makeText(context,
            context.getString(R.string.error_network_timeout),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
    //TODO
} else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
   //TODO
} else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
  //TODO
} else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
Toast.makeText(context,
            "ParseError",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
```

I get this message : ***ParseError***

Comment: Please include all the new code, not just one line.

Comment: the rest stays the same, I have just replaced the line : `JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");`  with this line : `JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response.toString());`

Comment: Hmm I see no reason why it would not work.  What do you mean by "does not work?"  Have you tested that your php page is returning the correct data?  At exactly what point in the code does it crash?  What is the message?  Please update question.

Comment: yes, I have checked the php json result. I get this result : `[{"0":"100","id":"100","1":"sandra","name":"sandra","2":"x@x.com","email":"x@x.com"}]`

Comment: Does it crash?  What do you mean "does not work."

Comment: if I print error of volley, i get this msg : `D/ViewRootImpl@874f84e[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
E/VOLLEY: ERROR
D/ViewRootImpl@874f84e[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
D/ViewRootImpl@874f84e[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 481862189568}`

Answer (score 0):

is this the exact output of php?

`[{"0":"100","id":"100","1":"sandra","name":"sandra","2":"x@x.com","email":"x@x.com"}]`

cause if thats the case you will get an error since there is no json array "data"
that is enclosing it.

Comment: I think, you did not read my question exactlly. I want to remove the "data" from my php code, but the volley should work after that

Comment: I get this message : ***ParseError*** . must the volley get data-name ? is not enough when the volley gets the json as array ?